# Android Studio Signed APK - Mandatory Manifest-Version attribute missing

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

This is my `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    google()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
        renderscriptTargetApi 22
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            buildConfigField "boolean", "CRASH_LOGGING", "true"
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            buildConfigField "boolean", "CRASH_LOGGING", "true"
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "regular"

    productFlavors {
        offmarket {
            applicationId "*********"
            versionCode 68
            versionName "4.0.1"
            dimension "regular"
        }
        samsung {
            applicationId "*********"
            versionCode 9
            versionName "4.0.3"
            dimension "regular"
        }
        playstore {
            applicationId "*********"
            versionCode 17
            versionName "4.0.4"
            dimension "regular"
        }
        amazon {
            applicationId "*********"
            versionCode 208
            versionName "3.8.7"
            dimension "regular"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        offmarketDebug {
            java.srcDirs += ["src/offmarketDebug/java"]
            res.srcDirs += ["src/offmarketDebug/res"]
        }
        offmarketRelease {
            java.srcDirs += ["src/offmarketRelease/java"]
            res.srcDirs += ["src/main/res"]
        }
        playstoreDebug {
            java.srcDirs += ["src/playstoreDebug/java"]
            res.srcDirs += ["src/playstoreDebug/res"]
            manifest.srcFile 'src/playstoreDebug/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
        playstoreRelease {
            java.srcDirs += ["src/playstoreRelease/java"]
            res.srcDirs += ["src/playstoreRelease/res"]
            manifest.srcFile 'src/playstoreRelease/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
        amazonDebug {
            java.srcDirs += ["src/amazonDebug/java"]
        }
        amazonRelease {
            java.srcDirs += ["src/amazonRelease/java"]
        }
        samsungDebug {
            java.srcDirs += ["src/samsungDebug/java"]
            manifest.srcFile 'src/samsungDebug/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
        samsungRelease {
            java.srcDirs += ["src/samsungRelease/java"]
            manifest.srcFile 'src/samsungRelease/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation "com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0"
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'

    compile('com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:1.4.7') {
        exclude group: 'xmlpull', module: 'xmlpull'
    }
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.9'
    compile('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1') {
        exclude module: 'stax'
        exclude module: 'stax-api'
        exclude module: 'xpp3'
    }
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.7'

    // UI & VIEWS
    compile 'com.tuyenmonkey:mkloader:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.mmin18:realtimeblurview:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:ValueBar:v1.0.2'

    // IMAGE HANDLING
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'

    // NETWORK HANDLING
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.0'

    //RETORFIT
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile('com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml:2.3.0') {
        exclude module: 'stax'
        exclude module: 'stax-api'
        exclude module: 'xpp3'
    }
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0'

    // FABRIC
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    // ADS
    compile 'com.flurry.android:analytics:8.2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.appbrain:appbrain-sdk:14.60@aar'
    compile(name: 'android-ad-sdk', ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: 'SOMAAndroid-9.1.5-release', ext: 'aar')
    compile 'com.applovin:applovin-sdk:+'

    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    samsungDebugImplementation files('libs/sdk-v1.0.0.jar')
    samsungDebugImplementation files('libs/motion-v2.2.2.jar')
    samsungReleaseImplementation files('libs/sdk-v1.0.0.jar')
    samsungReleaseImplementation files('libs/motion-v2.2.2.jar')

    //debug DB
    debugCompile 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.1'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And when i try to Sign my application to APK i get this error:

```
Mandatory Manifest-Version attribute missing
```

And this is the full error log:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':**:packagePlaystoreRelease'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:151)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:148)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:191)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:141)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:108)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: 1 exception was raised by workers:
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade

    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$WorkersBasedScheduler$transform$2.call(BuildElements.kt:165)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$WorkersBasedScheduler$transform$2.call(BuildElements.kt:129)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$WorkersBasedScheduler.into(BuildElements.kt:138)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElementActionScheduler.into(BuildElementActionScheduler.kt:37)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.doTaskAction(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:432)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NewIncrementalTask$taskAction$$inlined$recordTaskAction$1.invoke(AndroidVariantTask.kt:51)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NewIncrementalTask$taskAction$$inlined$recordTaskAction$1.invoke(AndroidVariantTask.kt:31)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Blocks.recordSpan(Blocks.java:91)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NewIncrementalTask.taskAction(NewIncrementalTask.kt:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalInputsTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalInputsTaskAction.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:41)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.execute(AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.java:25)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$5.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:393)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:376)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:213)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$0(ExecuteStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:201)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:70)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:89)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:77)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.workers.WorkerExecutorException: 1 exception was raised by workers:
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade

    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$WorkerExecutorAdapter.await(Workers.kt:284)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$WorkersBasedScheduler$transform$2.call(BuildElements.kt:163)
    ... 94 more
Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkerExecution.waitForCompletion(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:285)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:115)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForCompletion(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:87)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.await(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:150)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$WorkerExecutorAdapter.await(Workers.kt:282)
    ... 95 more
Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: Failed to generate v1 signature
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable.run(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:793)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade.run(Workers.kt:335)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:39)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:61)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:55)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$1.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:105)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$1.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:215)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:131)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to generate v1 signature
    at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.sign.SigningExtension.onOutputZipReadyForUpdate(SigningExtension.java:307)
    at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.sign.SigningExtension.access$200(SigningExtension.java:59)
    at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.sign.SigningExtension$1.lambda$beforeUpdate$2(SigningExtension.java:176)
    at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.notify(ZFile.java:2281)
    at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.update(ZFile.java:1012)
    at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.close(ZFile.java:1345)
    at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.zfile.ApkZFileCreator.close(ApkZFileCreator.java:173)
    at com.google.common.io.Closer.close(Closer.java:214)
    at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.IncrementalPackager.close(IncrementalPackager.java:329)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.doTask(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:697)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.access$300(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:128)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable.run(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:775)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mandatory Manifest-Version attribute missing
    at com.android.apksig.internal.jar.ManifestWriter.writeMainSection(ManifestWriter.java:47)
    at com.android.apksig.internal.apk.v1.V1SchemeSigner.generateManifestFile(V1SchemeSigner.java:363)
    at com.android.apksig.internal.apk.v1.V1SchemeSigner.sign(V1SchemeSigner.java:253)
    at com.android.apksig.DefaultApkSignerEngine.outputJarEntries(DefaultApkSignerEngine.java:657)
    at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.sign.SigningExtension.onOutputZipReadyForUpdate(SigningExtension.java:305)
    ... 33 more
```

Any suggestions what can be the problem? Maybe i missing something in my variant settings?

Answer (score 0):

Every app project must have an AndroidManifest.xml file (with precisely that name) at the root of the project source set. The manifest file describes essential information about your app to the Android build tools, the Android operating system, and Google Play. You need to check your Applications AndroidManifest.xml file It should look something like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```